# Road Trip Through Sedona, AZ

Tags: usa, sightseeing, road-trips, grand-canyon, arizona

I am renting a car to take a day or two road trip from Phoenix through Sedona, Arizona on our way to the Grand Canyon. Any recommended places to stop by and see?

While I'm by no means a new-age person, the "vortexes" seem interesting for their geological and Native American historical significance. Is there one to drive to and see for yourself?

I've also heard Jerome is a nice town to drive through.

Anything else?

Comment: Are you interested specifically in Sedona, or also other places between Phoenix and the Grand Canyon?

Answer (score 2):

I have only been to Sedona a few times but Slide Rock and Hiking are the only two suggestions I have.

If you like cliff jumping or swimming Slide Rock is a great place to start.
http://azstateparks.com/Parks/SLRO/index.html

Also, there is a ton of hiking and things to see. There are several great references through a google search. Unfortunately I always had a local or guide so I can't tell you exactly where I went myself but the entire area is beautiful.
http://www.greatsedonahikes.com/

Comment: As a follow up for anyone stumbling onto this post, check out Elote Cafe in Sedona for some kick ass food. The roasted duck empanada left me craving for more :P